# concatenate an address delete extra commas

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to concatenate addresses into a single field in table.

```
Create table temp(ID int, Address1 varchar(100),Address2 varchar(100),Address3 varchar(100),City varchar(100), State varchar(100))
Insert into temp(1,'2 Main St','','','Allentown','PA')
Insert into temp(2,'4 Bee St','PO Box 5067','','Bethlehem','PA')
Insert into temp(3,'Building Two','Suite 208, 707 Alexander Road,','Pembroke Park','Easton','PA')
```

I want to create a view that shows ID, Address as one field. i.e.

```
2 Main St, Allentown,PA
4 Bee St,PO Box 5067,Bethlehem,PA
Building Two,Suite 208, 707 Alexander Road,Pembroke Park,Easton,PA
```

.

```
Create VIEW [dbo].[vwtemp]
AS 
SELECT ID,
              isnull(Address1,NULL) AS "Address1",
              isnull(Address2,NULL) AS "Address2",
              isnull(Address3,NULL) AS "Address3",
              isnull(City,NULL) AS "City",
              isnull(State,NULL) AS "State",     
Stuff(  
     Coalesce(', ' + [Address1], '') 
   + Coalesce(', ' + [Address2],'') 
   + Coalesce(', ' + [Address3], '') 
   + Coalesce(', ' + [City], '') 
   + Coalesce(', ' + [State], '') 
)  from temp
```

The above query inserts extra commas when for ID 1  because Address3 & 2 are null ; ID=2 Address3 is null;

Any suggestions.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE CASE Statement while concatenating the strings CASE WHEN (Address2 IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE (', ' + Address2) END